# For MediaWiki Skin Setting HTML Title to "[Site Name]" instead of "Main Page - [Site Name]"

Tags: html, mediawiki, title, skin

I'm using a custom version of the monobook skin. How do I set the HTML title to "[Site Name]" instead of "Main Page - [Site Name]"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to put something like the following in your common.js, and get it to execute on only the Main Page.

```
if {{{{PAGENAME}}=="Main Page"
  {
  document.title = "{{SITENAME}}";
  }
```

It's not totally correct because I don't know javascript.

Comment: Thank you. I would prefer a way to get search engines to use this as the title but I'm happy with what you suggested. 'if (document.title=="Main Page | EMS Encyclopedia")
{
    document.title = "EMS Encyclopedia";
}'

Comment: Thank you. I would prefer a way to get search engines to use this as the title but I'm happy with what you suggested. 'if (document.title=="Main Page | EMS Encyclopedia")
{
    document.title = "EMS Encyclopedia";
}' I tried changing MediaWiki:Pagetitle-view-mainpage but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Try editing [[MediaWiki:Pagetitle]] - set it to "{{SITENAME}}" instead of the default "$1 - {{SITENAME}}".

Comment: I want $1 - {{SITENAME}} for everything but the main page.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use MediaWikis parser functions to achieve something like what Adrian Archer answered, but run by the server rather than the client (so search engines will take  heed). You'll have to edit [[MediaWiki:Pagetitle]] as Joshua C. Lerner said, then. Extension:ParserFunctions is bundled with MediaWiki 1.18 and above, so http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:ParserFunctions will help you!